# Sato-Tate for modular forms

Tags: modular-forms

Let $f$ be non-CM holomorphic modular forms of weight $k\geq 2$, and $a(p)$ be its $p^{th}$ Fourier-coefficient. the Sato–Tate conjecture is known to be true in this case, I want to know whether such a result is known with $a(p^n)'s$ (where $n$ is any natural number) as well.

Comment: The statement follows from the usual Sato-Tate conjecture and the Hecke relations between $a(p)$ and $a(p^n)$. However, it will be a different measure.

Comment: Got it, thanks!